# Accessing files in the same directory as script

Tags: ruby, relative-path, cwd

I need to access files that are relative to the location of my Ruby script.

The only solution I've found is using `File.dirname(__FILE__)`, however, if the script is run from a symlink, `__FILE__` gives the location of the symlink.

I would prefer a solution that does not involve looking at `__FILE__`, checking if it's a link, if it is, finding out where it points to. But, if there is no other way, it would be nice to know if there is already a gem to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

does `File.expand_path` help?

(don't have a 'nix box to try it on)

Comment: Not working on mine, also OS X. Maybe there's an option that needs to be set for it to do that? I'm using `File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))`

Comment: I'm just using File.expand_path(".") for a symlinked dir.  I'm running ruby 1.9 on max osx 10.6

Comment: I was using ruby 1.8, but installed 1.9 and still didn't work. I'll just write a function to test if it's a symlink, and follow if it is.

Comment: @Jeffrey Aylesworth: try reversing those operations: `File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))`

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the following variant: `File.expand_path('../other_file_in_same_dir', __FILE__)`

The second argument is the point from where the relative path will get expanded. This defaults to the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

You could always execute a shell command like ls -l $(pwd) with popen and parse it to follow the symlink.  For windows you would simply execute the equivalent windows os command (which I'm assuming exists!)

Comment: how do you even get a 'symlink' on windows?

Comment: You can't, but I need the script to work properly on Windows and *nix. (Windows does have a proprietary file format that acts like a symlink on Windows though, they're the .lnk files)

Comment: A .lnk is just a file, not a filesystem feature, and its purpose is somewhat different.

You can get Symbolic Links and Hard Links in Windows. I use them sometimes when I move a folder around and an old application requires the old path. You can find more information here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-symlinks-in-windows-vista/